# Laravel 6 Event Listener Mailable Queue unable to access

Tags: laravel, events, listener, laravel-6, laravel-queue

Environment:
php: **7.4.2**
laravel: **6.15.0**

**Scenario**: Upon user registration, `event(new NewUserHasRegisteredEvent($user));` is triggered.

In my `EventServiceProvider.php`

```
protected $listen = [
    NewUserHasRegisteredEvent::class => [
        \App\Listeners\WelcomeNewUserListener::class,
    ],
];
```

My `NewUserHasRegisteredEvent.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewUserHasRegisteredEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

My `WelcomeNewUserListener.php` **Note** that it `implements ShouldQueue`

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\NewUserHasRegisteredEvent;
use App\Mail\WelcomeUserMail;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class WelcomeNewUserListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(NewUserHasRegisteredEvent $event)
    {
        Mail::to($event->user->email)->send(new WelcomeUserMail($event->user));
    }
}
```

My `WelcomeUserMail.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class WelcomeUserMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails/new-welcome')
            ->with('user', $this->user);
    }
}
```

My `new-welcome.blade.php`

```
@component('mail::message')
Hello {{ $user->name ?? 'name' }}, ...
@endcomponent
```

**Issue:** When the user receives the registration email, the `$user->name` is not defined hence i'm using ?? operator. **Weird thing is** when I remove the `ShouldQueue` from the WelcomeNewUserListener.php then the $user->name works perfectly fine.

Please suggest. I want to use queue via event/listeners way.

Comment: In my understanding `shouldQueue` should not be put on a listener but on the `WelcomeUserMail`.

Comment: Thank you very much @ThomasVanderVeen. Please answer the question with the same response so that I can +1 it. Appreciate!