# Laravel Mail ShouldQueue unable to pass variables to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

There are many similar questions, the closest [Laravel 6 Event Listener Mailable Queue unable to access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60214279/laravel-6-event-listener-mailable-queue-unable-to-access).

php: 7.2
Laravel: 5.7

1. Controller:

```
public function send_email(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->json()->all();
    //data: {"to":"email@to.me","msg":"test message","subject":"test subject"}

    Mail::to($data['to'])->send(new MailFromNewinc( $data['subject'], $data['msg']));

    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'status_code' => 200
    ));
}
```

2. MailFromNewinc Mailable:

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class MailFromNewinc extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $msg;
    public $header;

    public function __construct($header, $msg)
    {
        $this->msg = $msg;
        $this->header = $header;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject($this->header)
                ->view('emails.sendmail_from_newinc');
    }
}
```

3. sendmail_from_newinc view:

```
<body>
{{ $header??'no header' }}
<br>
{{ $msg??'no content' }}
</body>
</html>
```

**Result:**
test subject
no content

If I remove `ShouldQueue` implements from mailable $msg is accessible, but if I leave in, $msg is null. No matter if I set in builder `->with('msg', $this->msg);`
$header is accessible in both ways.

**UPDATE**
If I change the variable name `$header` to something else (everywhere in the mailable and in the view) then it also stops working. Is it a reserved word?

If I leave in but change the subject :

```
return $this->subject('custom subject')->view('emails.sendmail_from_newinc');
```

the email still comes with subject defined in `$header` and not 'custom subject'. :O

I already try to render the mail in the controller:

```
return (new MailFromNewinc($data['subject'], $data['msg']))->render();
```

and it shows everything in order, all variables in place.

I don't know how I messed up, I have an another mailable, with almost same setting, but one $header and one custom model in the __construct function, and everything is accessible in its view as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I find the problem: I had to restart queue worker.
I don't really know how it is working, but something stuck in, because when I changed even the view in the mailable build function, it still sent with the previous view.
After queue restart everything works normal.